# Rails 3 - My message instead of strange validation message of nested_attributes model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have models **User**, **Teacher**, **TeacherEducation**. **TeacherEducation** belongs to **Teacher**, **Teacher** belongs to **User**. I use nested attributes to save everything via one line in my controller. But i get very strange names of fields for **TeacherEducation** when my app shows validation errors. For example:

```
Teacher teacher education teacher education university can't be empty.
```

I don't have `Teacher teacher education teacher education university` name, i set my own alias in **locales/en.yml**

```
en:
    activerecord:
        attributes:
         ...
          teacher_education:
            teacher_education_university: "Univer"
```

And i don't get such strange names in **User** or **Teacher** models. So, how can i show right message?

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor   :password                                                               
  attr_accessible :user_login,                                                           
                  :password,
                  :teacher_attributes
  has_one :teacher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher 
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :teacher_last_name,
                  :teacher_first_name,
                  :teacher_middle_name,
                  :teacher_birthday,
                  :teacher_sex,
                  :teacher_category,
                  :teacher_education_attributes
  belongs_to :user 
  has_one :teacher_education
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher_education
end

class TeacherEducation < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :teacher_education_university,
                    :teacher_education_year,
                    :teacher_education_graduation,
                    :teacher_education_speciality
    belongs_to :teacher  
    validates :teacher_education_university,   
              :presence   => { :message => "can't be empty" }            
end
```

My controller:

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
 def create_teacher   
     user = User.new( params[:user] ) 
 user.user_role = "teacher"                                                            

 if user.save 
   ...
 else
   all_err = user.errors.full_messages 
   ...
   user_errors = all_err.to_sentence :last_word_connector => ", ",
                                     :two_words_connector => ", "                                                                                                                                                    
   flash[:error] = user_errors if user_errors.present? 
 end 
end
```

My hash:

```
user: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  password: ''
  teacher_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    teacher_birthday: ''
    teacher_category: ''
    teacher_education_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      teacher_education_graduation: ''
      teacher_education_speciality: ''
      teacher_education_university: ''
      teacher_education_year: ''
    teacher_first_name: ''
    teacher_last_name: ''
    teacher_middle_name: ''
    teacher_sex: w
  user_login: ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the Teacher's TeacherEducation#teacher_education_university attribute is blank.

When you try to save the User, it's returning the error message for `@user.teacher.teacher_education`'s  teacher_education_university attribute.

Because you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, you can't save the @user record if it's Teacher is not valid. You can't save the Teacher if it's TeacherEducation is not valid.

Comment: I understand that. Can i show on the screen `Univer can't be empty.` instead of `Teacher teacher education teacher education university can't be empty.` ?

Comment: Ah...

Well, you're asking for the errors on User. You'll have to ask the @teacher_education directly for it's error message I think